# Is it possible to use promoted builds in Jenkins pipeline and trigger a pipeline job after approving through email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

i wanted to send an email to developers to do manual testing and a link to approve the build and then to do the build in production.Can anyone achieve this using jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can have a step on your pipeline as per below. They cannot approve it on the email, but you can send the URL of the job build on the email:

```
stage("Stage with input") {
    steps {
      def userInput = false
        script {
            // build your custom email message here
            emailext (
             subject: "Job: ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
             body: """Job ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_URL}]""",
             recipientProviders: "someone@somewhere.com"
            )

            def userInput = input(id: 'Proceed1', message: 'Promote build?', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'Please confirm you agree with this']])
            echo 'userInput: ' + userInput

            if(userInput == true) {
                // do action
            } else {
                // not do action
                echo "Action was aborted."
            }

        }    
    }  
}
```

Check [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/) email ext plugin.
And [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) the input step.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to approve it in Jenkins and post approvals deploy in production

Comment: Yes, the url will redirect the user to the paused Jenkins step waiting for approval

Comment: i am gettng error while using the above script and now i managed to fix the error but email is not triggering. below is my script emailext (
             subject: "Job: ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
             body: """Job ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_URL}]""",
             recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
             to: 'xxx@gmail.com'
            )